# How to restore the camera's default settings?

Tags: rendering, camera, image

How can I restore the default settings for my camera? Right now if you press the '0' key it renders the image vertically. It would be nice to have the horizontal camera back. Thanks!

https://we.tl/t-Q89rxpuUrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Restoring default values

You can restore any property in Blender's UI to its default value by hovering your mouse over it and pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> on your keyboard.

## Your file

In your case, you have the camera rotated, so you need to select it and change it's rotation that you can do in the Sidebar(n panel) right in the 3d viewport:

[image]

## Aspect ratio

You have vertical kind of portrait orientation resolution set in the output settings. I suspect this may not be what you want. You can change the aspect ratio in the Properties Editor, Output tab, Format section by changing Resolution X and Y values:

[image]

Note that there is also this confusing section in the same place:
[image]

These settings are absolutely useless and have nothing to do with the regular meaning of aspect ratio when we usually talk about images. They are there in case you decide to render content for devices that are a couple of decades old and have non square pixels. This should be left alone. In my personal opinion, the devs probably left it there just to mess with and confuse new users, but that's not a fact - just an opinion, that I should have probably kept to myself...

Comment: Just a sidenote on the _Aspect_ settings, it might confuse new (and even older) users, I don't think it's kept only for "devices that are a couple of decades old". This can be used to produce anamorphic results. Most people don't bother about getting a cinematic look etc. or trying to replicate a certain camera look and of course many things can be done in postproduction in different software. However, if you know you want to render something anamorphic to fit some other anamorphic footage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save any changes in your file you want to keep, if you haven't already.
2. Create a new file.
3. Select and Copy the default camera from your startup file.
4. Load your project file again.
5. Paste the default camera into your scene. Make sure it's selected.
6. [Set it as the Active Camera.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/camera_view.html#setting-the-active-camera)
7. Optionally, you can delete the other camera with the settings you don't want.

Instead of copy/pasting, you can also **Append** (File → Append...) data from another .blend file into your current one.

It's helpful to understand that cameras are objects that have their own camera setting **datablocks** (similar to mesh objects, curve objects, etc). And you can switch this camera data from a dropdown menu in the **Object Data Properties** tab.

[image]

<sup>Above: The camera object "Camera.001" is selected, and the camera data associated with it is being changed from "Camera.001" to "Camera".</sup>

Since the settings you adjust in the Object Data Properties tab are bound to the camera data, you can swap datablocks as you like. Just click the shield icon to assign a "fake user" to any unused datablocks you wish to keep, and this will prevent them from getting purged when you close your .blend file.

Comment: Many thanks to you all! These answers are very helpful.